# Whats the correct replacement for posix_memalign in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, posix

I currently trying to build word2vec in Windows. But there are problems with  `posix_memalign()` function. Everyone is suggesting to use `_aligned_malloc()`, but the number of parameters are different. So what's the best equivalent for `posix_memalign()` in Windows?

Comment: See: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12055862/253056)

Comment: `a = posix_memalign((void **)&syn1neg, 128, (long long)vocab_size * layer1_size * sizeof(real));`
How to change it to use malloc for example?

Comment: There is a [whole section in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs9stz4e.aspx) dedicated to data alignment on Windows. How about you read the documentation of the Windows function, then the documentation of the POSIX function, and then try to understand what parameter for what stands?

Comment: @HristoIliev If I wrote my own code I'd do it. I just need to build someone's else library. And If I'm afraid to build it incorrect (unexpected crushes or something). Just asked quick question for programmers who already face the same problem.

Comment: For completeness it also would be interesting to know which version of Windows you are targeting.

Comment: Just add `#define posix_memalign(p, a, s)  (((*(p)) = _aligned_malloc((s), (a))), *(p) ?0 :errno)` to your Windows build. :-)

Comment: @alk - thank you, short and probably best sollution. I checked it and it works )

Answer (score 10):

Thanks everyone. Based on code I fond in some repository and your advices I build EXE sucessfully. Here the code I used:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
static int check_align(size_t align)
{
    for (size_t i = sizeof(void *); i != 0; i *= 2)
    if (align == i)
        return 0;
    return EINVAL;
}

int posix_memalign(void **ptr, size_t align, size_t size)
{
    if (check_align(align))
        return EINVAL;

    int saved_errno = errno;
    void *p = _aligned_malloc(size, align);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        errno = saved_errno;
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    *ptr = p;
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

**UPDATE**:

Looks like @alk suggest the best sollution for this problem:

`#define posix_memalign(p, a, s) (((*(p)) = _aligned_malloc((s), (a))), *(p) ?0 :errno)`

Comment: The line in the update solved the problem for me

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not a drop-in replacement, because you're not allowed to use the regular `free()` with `_aligned_malloc()`.

Answer (score 5):

`_aligned_malloc()` should be decent replacement for `posix_memalign()` the arguments differ because `posix_memalign()` returns an error rather than set `errno` on failure, other they are the same:

```
void* ptr = NULL;
int error = posix_memalign(&ptr, 16, 1024);
if (error != 0) {
  // OMG: it failed!, error is either EINVAL or ENOMEM, errno is indeterminate
}
```

Becomes:

```
void* ptr = _aligned_malloc(1024, 16);
if (!ptr) {
  // OMG: it failed! error is stored in errno.
}
```

Comment: The value of `errno` is **indeterminate** after a call to `posix_memalign(3)`! Not the same as "not updated".

Comment: Note that the pointer returned by `posix_memalign` can be passed to `free`, but the pointer returned by `_aligned_malloc` must be passed to `_aligned_free`.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful that memory obtained from _aligned_malloc() must be freed with _aligned_free(), while posix_memalign() just uses regular free(). So you'd want to add something like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define posix_memalign_free _aligned_free
#else
#define posix_memalign_free free
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

if you compare `possix_memalign` declaration:

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

with `_aligned_malloc` declaration:

```
void * _aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment);
```

you see that `_aligned_malloc` is missing `void **memptr` param, but it returns `void *` instead.

If your code was something like this:

```
void * mem;
posix_memalign(&mem, x, y);
```

now it will be (take notice that `x, y` is now `y, x`):

```
void * mem;
mem = _aligned_malloc(y, x);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch it was permuted.

Comment: There is a subtle difference. The POSIX function requires that the alignment is both a multiple of `sizeof(void *)` and a power of two. The Windows CRT function relaxes that requirement to only a power of two (i.e. not a multiple of the pointer size). This is only relevant when porting from Windows to POSIX since the requirement is always satisfied in the opposite case.

Answer (score 0):

Since C11, there is [`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) in the C standard library.

The memory can be freed with a regular `free`, which is the main advantage of this function, compared to `_aligned_malloc`/`_aligned_free`.

```c
int *p2 = aligned_alloc(1024, 1024*sizeof *p2);
printf("1024-byte aligned addr: %p\n", (void*)p2);
free(p2);
```

However, the ease of use with `free` is precisely the reason why Visual Studio is unlikely to ever implement it, see [std::aligned_alloc() missing from visual studio 2019?c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962839/stdaligned-alloc-missing-from-visual-studio-2019c).